# After move magento to other server white screen

Tags: magento-1.9

After i moved the a magento webshop http://www.delaviesportvoeding.nl/ ( change your host file to ip 149.210.132.3 to see the website ) i get a white screen. No erros facing up. I allready set up ini display errors. when i change the template it works so it must be something in the template.

some one can help me out?

Thnx!

Comment: when I access 149.210.132.3, it gives the default "Apache is functioning normally " message, something is not setup as it should on your server , maybe the `DocumentRoot`

Comment: see server error log

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure your php.ini allows error_reporting and display_errors
- check php error log
- check nginx/apache error log
- check magento error log
- check magento var/reports

Comment: I did and check it all. i think its a PHP configuration error or something

Comment: If you have a white screen, either there is no output or you have php error. HTTP Status Code 500 is a php error. Finding a reason why nothing is echoed is a harder task. But I'm quite sure it is an error. And I had lots of php installations which didn't output any error and all of them were configuration mistakes. Once fixed I saw the errors.